# How can I write this equations and symbols in latex?

Tags: math-mode

Hope you are doing great!

I want to convert this equations and symbols in latex!

[image]

**Any kind of solution, suggestion, or hints I need.**

Thanks in an advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a start:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}[c]
            \text{depth:}\ d =\alpha^{\phi} \\
            \text{width:}\ w = \beta^{\phi} \\
            \text{resolution:}\ r = \gamma^{\phi} \\
            &\hspace{-1cm} s.t.\alpha.\beta^{2}.\gamma^{2} \approx 2 \\
            &\hspace{-1cm} \alpha\geq 1,\beta\geq1,\gamma\geq 1
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Roland. It's a great help. Til now I am a newbie so that I can't upvote. Thanks again.

Comment: You *really* should put `depth:` into `\text{depth:}` (and similar for the others)

Comment: You should align the `=`, as in the OP.

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce the picture: what I get is

[image]

from the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
\text{depth: } d &= \alpha^\phi \\
\text{width: } w &= \beta^\phi \\
\text{resolution: } r &= \gamma^\phi \\
&\text{s.t. }\alpha.\beta^2.\gamma^2\approx2 \\
&\alpha\ge1,\beta\ge1,\gamma\ge1
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, this is not a particularly good way to do that display.

1. The text and math fonts don't match. Notwithstanding that the `times` package has been deprecated for more than 20 years, there are still document classes that use it.
2. The alignments are awkward. There is no reason for the colons not to be aligned, nor for the conditions to be placed somewhere (I can clearly see where they are placed, because I know LaTeX, readers won't).
3. The period (on the baseline) should never be used as a multiplication symbol.

A possible improvement, using NewTX to get matching text and math fonts based on Times

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{alignedat}{2}
  &\text{depth: }      & d &= \alpha^\phi \\
  &\text{width: }      & w &= \beta^\phi \\
  &\text{resolution: } & r &= \gamma^\phi
\end{alignedat} \\
&\begin{aligned}
  \text{s.t. } & \alpha\beta^2\gamma^2\approx2 \\
               &\alpha\ge1,\beta\ge1,\gamma\ge1
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot learn a lot. Don't know why I downvoted. Demotivation for me.

Comment: @Md.AsifIqbalFahim Somebody possibly downvoted because you didn't show any effort in trying to solve the problem yourself.